# Debug output from Sony Xperia XA1 not working

Tags: android, sony

I recently sold my Samsung S5 minis I used for testing my android apps, and switched to a Sony Xperia XA1. However, I cannot get the debug output to work.

Every 0.5 seconds I just get "Enter while loop" debug message, and that is all I get.

I have installed the ADB Xperia XA1 driver downloaded from sony developer website, and the phone is seen in devicemanager, so am I missing some setting somewhere, or is it just not possible to debug with the XA1 ?

I am using Windows 7 64 bit and newest stable android studio release.

Comment: Just picked up an XA1 Ultra and I'm also getting an ever-increasing-rate of "enter while loop" messages, seemingly from the app I'm debugging.  Definitely not my code.  Initially it was one every 2 seconds, and now I'm getting dozens per second.  My debug output is otherwise getting through, but it's getting drowned

Comment: Did you find a  solution for this?